# WS-Notification implementation via WCF

Tags: wcf, ws-notification

I have a task to create a WCF-service, which is based on WS-Notification(in fact, WS-BaseNotification) protocol and i don't know how can i implement it. How can i generate a valid wsdl for these protocol and how can i format a soap envelope of my service. I'll be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 3):

In 3.5 there was no implementation for the WS-Notification standard ([source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/ab725cf6-19dd-4cf7-bc92-2bed111ea95c)), if doubt it is implemented in 4.0 or 4.5 so you have to do most of the implementation yourself. Maybe a good place to start is [WS-Eventing-for-WCF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14343/WS-Eventing-for-WCF-Indigo).